# Can't run Venv in VsCode

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, zsh, python-venv

For the last 3 days, I have been trying to set up virtual Env on Vs Code for python with some luck but I have a few questions that I cant seem to find the answer to.

1. Does Vs Code have to run in WSL for me to use venv?
2. When I install venv on my device it doesn't seem to install a Scripts folder inside the vevn folder. Is this out dated information or am I installing it incorrectly. I am installing onto Documents folder inside my D: drive using python3 - m venv venv. The folder does install and does run in WSL mode but I am trying to run it in clear VsCode so I can use other add-ons such as AREPL that doesn't seem to like being ran in WSL.

For extra context I have oh-my-ZSH set up and using the ubuntu command line on my windows device. Any information will be helpful at this point because I am losing my mind.

[venv folder in side D: drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FHoW.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecbDq.png)

Answer (score 3):

Run **`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope process`** before activating virtual environment.

All the best

Answer (score 2):

If you have the python extension installed you should be able to select your python interpreter at the bottom.

[image: python interpreter selection at the bottom of vscode]

You should then be able to select the appropriate path
[image: selecting the python interpreter]

Comment: Yes i am able to see this when I am running in WSL. The venv option, however does not work when I am not running in WSL. So do I have to run it in WSL?

Comment: The python extension might be installed on WSL as opposed to locally on windows which is why it may not be appearing. See docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_managing-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a virtual environment under WSL, it will work anywhere. But the reason you don't have a `Scripts/` directory is because (I bet) you're running VS Code with git bash and that makes Python think you're running under Unix. In that case it creates a `bin/` directory. That will also confuse VS Code because the extension thinks you're running under Windows.

I would either create a virtual environment using a Windows terminal like PowerShell or Command Prompt or use WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

> Run powershell as adminstrator
> then excute this; `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
> then type; `y` Enter

Now you can activate in vs code without restrictions every time.